# How to fix throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.')

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

[code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKz9d.png)

please help me on how I can fix the error

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to SO. Perhaps you should give us more information: show us your code (four spaces at the start of the line will show your code in a formatted state), what you would expect to happen and maybe a screen shot of what *is* happening.  Also, try taking the [tour] and reading the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling `res.render` two times.

First time it is being called and after fetching from `Passwords` model, it is called again.

Remove the `res.render` outside of the promise chain.

`res.render` or `res.end` or `res.send` or `res.json` ends the response writestream, so after it is closed you cannot write to it again.